# Magento Checkout page not loading fully

Tags: magento

I recently moved my magento site from my localhost to the live server - everything had been working perfectly on the localhost but when I moved it across quite a few errors turned up. I've managed to get rid of most of these but I've just come across this:

[image]

The Checkout page is only partially loading and I really have no idea why this is happening and how to go about fixing it :(

I'm guessing that the Billing Information section is the stumbling block but why would this be? Could there be a problem retrieving information from the DB? - and how could I go about testing that. "#checkout-step-billing" is loading but it is defaulting to display none and nothing after that point has loaded.

Would greatly appreciate any help and advice on this.

Comment: Can you check your server error logs? It seems the php is generating a fatal error. Your error log can provide more detailed information on this.

Comment: that looks suspiciously like you're hitting the memory limit, try raising the memory_limit on the server, and enable caching, this will make it less memory hungry.

Comment: Thank you!! - it was a problem with the memory_limit

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below so we can remove this from the unanswered list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by increasing the memory_limit in the php.ini file.

Instructions on how to do this here: https://drupal.org/node/207036